# How to deploy a Zend new project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently trying to update a previous web site using Zend Framework.

As I dont want to work in a local network, I subscrided to a pro offer of OVH server.

So I put my old website in the www folder, I uploaded the Zend Framework directory (ZendFramework-1.11.11), and then created a foder dev in the root directory as well.

As I got this error when I try to create a new project with putty :
**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in **xxxx/ZendFramework-1.11.11/bin/zf.php** on line **38**
This seems to come because the serveur is running with php 4 instead of 5.
I created a .htaccess file including the following line :
    SetEnv PHP_VER 5

When I use phpinfo(); in www/phpversion.php, it says it is PHP5. ...

But when I use php -v with putty, it keeps saying I am using php 4.4.9

Annyone has an idea to help me upgrading the server php version, and to help me creating my new project ??

Many thanks

Comment: FYI - Zend does NEED PHP5 - and SETENV PHP_VER 5 does not Change the PHP Version, it's just an environment variable. Speak to your host about this problem (phpinfo and putty talking about different versions). Ask them to upgrade your server to PHP 5 and then you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a LAMP setup with debian as the operating system do this as root:

aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-cli

and then retry. You may add some other packages like php5-gd or php5-suhosin etc.